# SQL (Oracle) - Select where record does not exist or another column in the 2nd table is true

Tags: sql, oracle

```
      Applications-Table  
    ---------------------
ID          FIRST_NAME          LAST_NAME          APPLICATION_TYPE          STATUS_TYPE
123         JOHN                SMITH              EDUCATION                 APPROVED
456         JANE                DOE                EDUCATION                 APPROVED
789         SARA                JANE               EDUCATION                 APPROVED
321         BOB                 KANE               GENERAL                   APPROVED
879         OLIVER              QUEEN              GENERAL                   APPROVED

     Assignments-Table
ID          APPLICATION_ID         INACTIVE
0001        456                    0
0002        789                    1
```

I am trying to write a sql statement that looks at tables similar to the example above.  What I need for results is a record that exists in the applications table that has an application type of education and a status type of approved but does not have a record in the assignments table.  However if a record exists in the assignments table then the Inactive column has to be 1.  Below is the sql I've been working with

```
SELECT 
    application.ID,
    application.FIRST_NAME,
    application.LAST_NAME,
FROM applications application
LEFT JOIN assignments assignment ON application.ID = assignment.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE application.STATUS_TYPE = 'APPROVED' 
AND application.APPLICATION_TYPE = 'EDUCATION'
AND assignment.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL OR assignment.INACTIVE != 0
```

I also tried the below sql but then I get John Smith, Jane Doe, and Sara Jane.

```
    SELECT 
        application.ID,
        application.FIRST_NAME,
        application.LAST_NAME,
    FROM applications application
    LEFT JOIN assignments assignment ON application.ID = 
    assignment.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE application.STATUS_TYPE = 'APPROVED' 
AND application.APPLICATION_TYPE = 'EDUCATION'
AND (assignment.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL OR assignment.INACTIVE != 0)
```

The records I'd expect to get back would be John Smith and Sara Jane.  Currently I am getting those 2 records and Jane Doe which I do not want in my results set.

Comment: Any time you have `AND` and `OR` in your where clause, you need to use parens to ensure it's doing what you want. Try `and (assignment.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL OR assignment.INACTIVE != 0)`.

Comment: I added the results of using () in my original post.

Comment: @crmckain . . . Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from applications a
where a.STATUS_TYPE = 'APPROVED' and
      a.APPLICATION_TYPE = 'EDUCATION' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from assignments am
                  where a.ID = am.APPLICATION_ID and am.inactive <> 1
                 );
```

If you want to express this using `left join`, the logic is:

```
select a.*
from applications a left join
     assignments am
     on a.ID = am.APPLICATION_ID and am.inactive <> 1
where a.STATUS_TYPE = 'APPROVED' and
      a.APPLICATION_TYPE = 'EDUCATION' and
      am.application_id is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f144d0164135101f74f780d144e67f13) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: So the bottom query using the left join I get the expected results but for Sara Jane I am getting null for application_Id and both records have status type of 0 even though John Smith doesn't have a record at all in that table and Sara Jane doesn't have an active record in that table because the default value of status type is 0

Comment: @crmckain . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This appears to be doing *exactly* what your question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use left join table column in  where condition  (otherwise this work as an inner join )

```
SELECT 
    application.ID,
    application.FIRST_NAME,
    application.LAST_NAME,
FROM applications application
LEFT JOIN assignments assignment ON application.ID = assignment.APPLICATION_ID
 AND ( assignment.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL OR assignment.INACTIVE != 0)
WHERE application.STATUS_TYPE = 'APPROVED' 
AND application.APPLICATION_TYPE = 'EDUCATION'
AND assignment.APPLICATION_ID is null
```

you should move these in related  ON clause  and let in where only the condition for null  values  (not in)

Comment: I'm getting the same results.

Comment: yes neither unfortunately provides me the expected results

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT appl.id,
       appl.first_name,
       appl.last_name
FROM   applications appl
WHERE  appl.application_type = 'EDUCATION'
  AND  appl.status_type = 'APPROVED'
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   assignments asgn
                   WHERE  appl.id = asgn.application_id
                     AND  asgn.inactive = 0)
```